# What would cause a printer to print noise instead of a document?

Tags: microsoft-office, printer

We've got a large MFP that the whole office shares. Everyone can use it fine as a general rule, but occasionally, a computer will start printing static instead of whatever was sent.

If I re-install the drivers on that machine, the problem is usually (although not always) resolved but this issue reappears on a weekly basis and I'd like to elimate it altogether.

Another thing I've noticed is that it tends to happen when printing from Word or Excel, but not notepad or Windows' own test page.

This is what they look like.

[image: Noisy documents from the printer]

Comment: is it laser or inkjet? its not because of the drivers. based on the technology inkjet or laser. the problem will differ

Comment: It's a laser printer. A Sharp MX2310U

Comment: I would suggest you contact the manufacturer and ask them.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Unfortunately, I've been unable to find a UK number for them that relates to printers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what caused this issue in the first place, but no amount of engineer visits and replaced parts would resolve it. In the end, we replaced the printer and we haven't seen it with the new one.

Apologies that there isn't more to it than that.

Answer (score -1):

The **OPC drum or the corona wire** is not functioning properly.

Try **replacing the cartridge** with a new one. If doesnt work(99% should work fine) contact the repair person.

Comment: Is this likely to be the case when one employee can print fine and another cannot?

Comment: does the same employee always gets the black page?
it doesnot depend on the user who prints on. Printers always get hardware related issues in most of the time

Comment: There are two computers known to me on which the issue occurs and it's not usually simultaneous.

Comment: Anbu: Since this problem can be fixed from the PC, and does not occur in pure text, it is unlikely to be a printer hardware issue. This appears to graphic related, rather than printing in text mode using the printer fonts. To test this, the next time a machine shows this problem, cancel the current print job at the PC and at the printer, and then print a text file from Notepad from the PC with the issue, followed by printing a picture, e.g. from MS Paint.